# How to pass date in javascript without it being manipulated

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, datetime, time

I have date and time stored in my database, and when I want to fetch it. It gets manipulated into another date and time.

I'm sending this date directly as an email, I mean it is being fetched from the database and sent as email, all in done in the server.
When I fetched the date on my client side, its what I expect, but its different in the email

An example is me having the following date and time saved;
1pm, August 1.

When I fetch it from my server, I get 12pm, july 31.

This only occurs on my production server, I mean if I run this on my local pc it get back exactly 1pm August 1.

But on my server hosted on both aws ec2, and heroku, I would get 12pm july 31

Comment: if you can give us the exact format of date and time stored in DB will help us more to give how to convert that into UTC

Answer (score 0):

Get your time and convert it into `UTC` time and date then on receiving side just convert back into local time from `UTC`

```js
const myDate = "2020-07-31T23:00:00.000Z"; //from DB
const utcDate = new Date(myDate).toUTCString(); // on receiving end

console.log(utcDate)
```

Comment: This is what the time looks like  `2020-07-31T13:00:00.000+00:00`,  this is what the date is `2020-07-31T23:00:00.000Z`

Comment: Which language are you susing, Java, Javascript, nodejs ?

Comment: javascript, I'm fetching it from the database using nodejs

Comment: check my answer .

Comment: The thing is, I'm sending this date directly as an email, I mean it is being fetched from the database and sent as email, all in done in the server.
When I fetched the date on my client side, its what I expect, but its different in the email

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by setting a default timezone for my server to use in processing the dates and time.
I made use of moment-timezone.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely timezone issue. Your production server and your system were in different zones.

Comment: Is there any way around this? What do you suggest?

Comment: There are no two timezones that differ from each other by 25 hours. The most common scenario is UTC vs local, which is a maximum of +14 hours. The largest westerly offset is -10, so maximum of 25 hrs (Honolulu vs Kiribati), which would be extremely rare on the web.